# Segundo Error al crear una base de datos

Tags: mysql

Pues bien tuve que desistanlar la base de datos y volver a crearla y ahora cuando tuve que crearla de nuevo al introducir los datos de préstamo me da este error y no se porque. (Antes no se daba ese error).

*insert into PRESTAMO values (120, 2894123, 5023024, 6, to_date('26/3/1997', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), to_date('12/4/1997', 'dd/mm/yyyy'));*

**ERROR 1305 (42000): FUNCTION biblioteca.to_date does not exist**

**TODOS LOS DATOS QUE HE CARGADO SON DE ESE TIPO**

Comment: Ahí indica que se trata de usar una función que no existe por qué tal vez no ha sido declarada

Comment: no existe esa funcion en mysql. habrias tenido una armada vos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

si es mysql deberías usar la función STR_TO_DATE para convertir cadena a fecha

ejemplo:

```
STR_TO_DATE('26/3/1997', '%Y/%m/%d')
```